# How include object and implements interfaces of other projects in a spring mvc project?

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-mvc

Hi I am developing a Spring MVC rest services and need a modular project. For this, I have 3 java application projects (interfaces, implements interfaces and beans objects) but i can't include this in my Spring project. I am trying to import the a xml of each project but this in not working.

beans-context.xml (object project)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean>
        <property name="Empresa">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Empresa</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean>
        <property name="Operador">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Operador</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean>
        <property name="Dispositivo">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Dispositivo</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean>
        <property name="Sucursal">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Sucursal</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean>
        <property name="Receptor">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Receptor</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean>
        <property name="Vehiculo">
            <value type="java.lang.Class">cl.securityAuthentication.beans.Vehiculo</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

businnes-context.xml (interfaceImpl)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean name="empresaService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceEmpresaImpl"/>

    <bean name="operadorService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceOperadorImpl"/>

    <bean name="dispositivoService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceDispositivoImpl"/>

    <bean name="sucursalService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceSucursalImpl"/>

    <bean name="receptorService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceReceptorImpl"/>

    <bean name="vehiculoService" class="cl.securityAuthentication.business.ServiceVehiculoImpl"/> 
</beans>
```

applicationcontext.xml (spring project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:webservice.properties"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basenames">
             <list> 
                 <value>webapp-messages</value>
             </list>
         </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="classpath*: cl.securityAuthentication.business.business-context.xml"></import>
    <import resource="classpath*: cl.securityAuthentication.beans.beans-context.xml"></import>    
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bank</groupId>
    <artifactId>website</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>website</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>securityAuthenticationBeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>cl.securityAuthentication.beans</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>/home/patricio/Escritorio/securityAuthenticationBeans/dist/securityAuthenticationBeans.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>securityAuthenticationInterfaceBusiness</groupId>
                <artifactId>cl.securityAuthentication.interfaceBusiness</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>/home/patricio/Escritorio/securityAuthenticationInterfaceBusiness/dist/securityAuthenticationInterfaceBusiness.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>  


            <dependency>
                <groupId>securityAuthenticationBusiness</groupId>
                <artifactId>cl.securityAuthentication.Business</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>/home/patricio/Escritorio/securityAuthenticationBusiness/dist/securityAuthenticationBusiness.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency> 

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9968</stopPort>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                           <port>9099</port>
                           <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
                            <value>./src/main/resources/logback.xml</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[this is my folder projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz2Es.png)

help please :)

Answer (score 0):

The *XML* context declaration file path should be mentionned following the standardized String representation in the `<import>` tag, i.e. the items separator should be a **/** (slash) not a **.** (period).

```xml
<import resource="classpath*:cl/securityAuthentication/business/business-context.xml"></import>
<import resource="classpath*:cl/securityAuthentication/beans/beans-context.xml"></import>
```